# Sliders don't work after respawning (Roblox Exploiting)

Tags: roblox

I am working on a script for a roblox game and I added sliders for walkspeed and jumppower.
And everytime I "die" or reset my character the sliders do not work anymore.

Any fixes?

UILib with documentation: https://xheptcofficial.gitbook.io/kavo-library/

Walkspeed code:

```lua
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid;

--Walkspeed
WJSection:NewSlider("WalkSpeed", "Changes the player's Walkspeed", 200, 16, function(WSValue)
    Player.WalkSpeed = WSValue
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the player variable just to your local player and then in the slider get to the humanoid, this should fix it.

```
local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer

WJSection:NewSlider("WalkSpeed", "Changes the player's Walkspeed", 200, 16, function(WSValue)
    Player.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed = WSValue
end)
```